# Move Non-Active google sheet with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to move a NON active google sheet to a specific position or to insert it into a specific position with Google App Script.

Yes I could make it the active sheet and move it that way I am aware but I want to avoid that! This is the documentation that I can find on that: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveActiveSheet(Integer)

The issue is that because the script programmatically creates the sheet, names it and fills in a bunch of data I do not want to have to make it the active sheet. It seems needless to make the sheet the active sheet just so that I can move its position to where I want it. At no point do I ever call `ActiveSheet` in the entire script and would like to keep it that way.

If there is a way please let me know! I am afraid that the answer is going to be no as I cannot find a way to do it.

This is the code that I am using to create a sheet but have no way to move it around:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MySheetIDHere')
var tempsheet = sheet.getSheetByName('SheetTemp');
tempsheet.copyTo(sheet).setName('New Sheet Name');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex, options)` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-sheetindex,-options).

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MySheetIDHere')
var tempsheet = sheet.getSheetByName('SheetTemp');
var pos = 3;
sheet.insertSheet('New Sheet Name', pos, {template: tempsheet});
```

`pos` is "*The index of the newly created sheet. To insert a sheet as the first one in the spreadsheet, set it to 0.*"

If you run this script with any of the other sheets active, the script makes the copy and places it at `pos` but does not activate either `tempsheet` or the newly copied sheet.

Is this what you need?

Comment: It looks like this will work but I do have one concern with it the change. The new method of `insertSheet()` says that "Inserts a new sheet into the spreadsheet, using a default sheet name. The new sheet becomes the active sheet." whereas the `copyTo()` method does not mention that it makes it the active sheet at all. Also where can I get more information on the `options` parameter that takes an `Object` with `Optional JavaScript advanced arguments.' Lastly maybe explain the difference between making it the active sheet vs not

Comment: Additionally, I would revise your last line of the code to `sheet.insertSheet('New Sheet Name', pos, {template: tempsheet});` it would be cleaner. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-sheetindex,-options

Comment: (1) I agree that the `insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex, options)` method would be cleaner. I have changed my post to reflect that. (2) The documentation says that the new sheet will become active. But when I ran this script on a dummy spreadsheet the new sheet was created in the background and _did not_ become the active sheet.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Through the native SpreadsheetApp Class, this operation is not achievable without activating a Sheet.

You can use the traditional Spreadsheet API though. Activate the Advanced Spreadsheet Service going to `Resources > Advanced Google Services > Sheets API`. In this example I will use the version 4.

In order to achieve your goal I would use an UpdateSheetProperties request that will modify its index to any available one.

```
From:
Sheet1(Active), Sheet2, Sheet3

To:
Sheet1(Active), Sheet3, Sheet2
```

First, I will save the sheet_id of the sheet I want to move.

```js
// In this case I will select the sheet in position 2 (index 1)
let sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("spreadsheet-id").sheets;
let sheet1_id = sheets[1].properties.sheetId;
```

No It's time to prepare the request:

```js
// I will use the built-in classes to emulate the proper JSON object described in the documentation.
let batch = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
let request = Sheets.newUpdateSheetPropertiesRequest();
request.fields = "index"; // This specifies I want to update only the index (position)
let properties = Sheets.newSheetProperties();
properties.sheetId = sheet1_id; // This selects the Sheet I want to update
properties.index = 3; // This is the new index (position) I want to move my Sheet to. This request will shift all the others Sheets accordingly. (Bear in mind that if it's current index the update request will be ignored)
request.properties = properties;
```

Now it's time to build the batch Request object and to actually perform the API call:

```js
batch.requests = [{
    "updateSheetProperties": request
}];
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batch, "spreadsheet-id");
}
```

### Reference

[Spreadsheet API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)

[Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)